# Typeahead not working with Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.1, bootstrap-typeahead

I wonder why this is not pulling records from the database. I have been on this for days. All I want to do is use typeahead to select matching record from the db. When a user enters a character, the matching records should be displayed so that the user can select the relevant value. I hope a kind heart would help me resolve this.

THis is the controller:

```
public function SelectLocationPlaces(UserAdressRequest $userAdressRequest)
        {
             if($userAdressRequest->isMethod('post'))
             {
                if($userAdressRequest->has('query'))
                {
                    $query = $userAdressRequest->get('query');
                    $locationPlaces = LocationPlaces::where('name', 'like', "%{$query}%")->toArray();
                    return json_encode($locationPlaces);
                }
             }
        }
```

This is the blade form:

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'created-products', 'method' => 'post'), array('id'=>'createproduct')) !!}
{!! Form::token() !!}

    <link href="{!! asset('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css') !!}" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="{!! asset('css/style.css') !!}" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">-->
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>

<p>{!! Form::select('countries', array('-1' => 'Select a Country') + $listedCountries) !!} </p>
<div class='well'>
    <p>{!! Form::text('query', '', array('id'=>'typeahead', 'data-provider'=>'typeahead')) !!}</p>
</div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{!! asset('bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js') !!}" type="text/javascript" />

    <script>
        $(function(){
                $('#typeahead').typeahead({
                    source: function(query, process){
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '{{ url('json/redirects/') }}',
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: 'query=' +query,
                            dataType: 'JSON',
                            async: true,
                            success: function(data){
                                process(data);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
    </script>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

This is the route:

```
Route::post('json/redirects', array('before'=>'csrf', 'uses'=>'UserAddressController@SelectLocationPlaces'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't written what's the problem - if it's exception or something else, but instead of:

```
$locationPlaces = LocationPlaces::where('name', 'like', "%{$query}%")->toArray();
```

you should rather use:

```
$locationPlaces = LocationPlaces::where('name', 'like', "%{$query}%")->get()->toArray();
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried this but yet to get it working. I wonder why it's not working.

Comment: @kehinde So do we, considering you aren't telling us what happens when you try it.

Comment: The problem is hard to debug. I have checked all references where I could sniff to see if anything goes wrong but nothing has been shown. On the console, no error log, using chrome dev tools, likewise, Laravel reports no error.